# Why is the object changes length while rotating?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, 2d

I'm trying to make an object (weapon) rotating toward the mouse position.But i have encountered a problem that this object somehow, rotates not only in z-axis, so with rotation it becames longer and smaller.

Here is the picture of problem

[image: With rotation the lenght of weapon is increasing]

Here's the code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class Rotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 mouseP;       
    void Update()
    {
        mouseP = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector3 direct = transform.position - mouseP;
        direct.Normalize();
        float Angle = Mathf.Atan2(direct.y, direct.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        Quaternion rotate = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, Angle);
        transform.rotation = rotate;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this happening because at this line: `Quaternion rotate = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, Angle);` I directle wrote that rotation should happen only on z-axis.
Any ideas how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because its parent object is also scaled? -> the two scales add up .. it looks like it is nested under the green block which is bigger in Y direction => also the child is bigger in Y direction

> Any ideas how can i solve this problem?

Well, the most trivial would be to not scale the parent objects.

In general I personally would strictly separate the object roots itself (all unscaled) and only scale the leaf children containing the visuals.

In your case I would e.g. use a hierarchy like

```
- PlayerRoot (unscaled)
  |-- PlayerBody (scaled green block)
  |-- Point (unscaled)
      |-- GunSprite (scaled grey block with local translation)
```

This way it is ensured there is no scaling in the entire hierarchy of the gun and you can rotate the `Point` object without facing any scaling issues

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I at least  know that the problem was in hierarchy.